# How can I view pdf files from an API with Vue Js?

Tags: django, api, vue.js

Hello friends I need your support.. I am currently developing an app with django rest framework in the backend and vue js in the frontend.. the app consists of saving pdf files, which I can list in a table.. but the problem is that it only I can see by table the path where they are saved and I have not been able to view the files. Can someone tell me how I can place a button to view these files?

I have tried functions to download the files but I have not achieved a solution

Comment: Please don't write in `ALL CAPS` as it is considered shouting on the net.

Comment: [vue-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-pdf)